# Swift 3.0 Update Annotation on Pin

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have an annotation on my pins for my mapView. On my annotation, I have a button and I want to be able to change the button image (from plus to minus) when the user clicks on the button. I am not sure where I can update this. I currently have my button image set up when the user clicks on the pin. The image itself won't update until I reload the map, but I am looking to update the button on the annotation view immediately after the user clicks on it. I am not sure how to update the button while the annotation is popped up.

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

    if let annotation = view.annotation as? MKPointAnnotation {
                let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
                view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
                if annotation.accessibilityValue! == "Minus" {

                    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
                    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "minus"), for: .normal)
                    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MapVC.minus), for: .touchUpInside)
                    view.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button
                } else {
                    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
                    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "plus"), for: .normal)
                    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MapVC.plus), for: .touchUpInside)
                    view.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button
                }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `didSelect` delegate method. When the user clicks on the button, `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method is called. You can change the button image in this delegate method.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    if control == view.leftCalloutAccessoryView {
        let button = control as! UIButton
        if annotation.accessibilityValue! == "Minus" {
            button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "minus"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "plus"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I able to change the pin annotation color in this delegate too?

Comment: Yes, you can. `let pin = view as! MKPinAnnotationView;
pin.pinTintColor = .blue`